# Describing shipping service on a paypal shopping cart?

Tags: paypal

I'm passing along variables to a paypal shopping cart(using the api and paypal payment standard). I can pass the shipping cost, but how, or is it possible to describe the shipping method on paypal form? I can't for the life of me find where or how this is done.

Example, 
my widget.... $1
shipping and Handling....$12

What I'd like:

my widget.... $1
shipping and Handling....$12 
(UPS Ground)

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure that passing the shipping provider to PayPal is possible. You might be able to pass it as a separate variable or some type of custom variable. If you only have one shipping provider you might be able to do the following

1. Log into your PayPal account
2. Go to **Profile > My Selling Tools**
3. Underneath Shipping my items click the **Update** button aligned with 'Shipping Preferences'
4. Select your default shipping carrier and press **Save**

Comment: thanks Kyle, don't think that would work for me though. I have a pulldown that has different shipping methods, the price gets estimated via ups api, then I pass the shipping cost along to paypal. Can't for the life of me see a way to pass or describe the chosen shipping method with paypals api.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass over the shipping description/provider.  However the feature only works with Express Checkout and with Website Payments Standard (cart upload method).  You would use this when using the Instant Update API.  You can find more about this in developers guide, and there is a section [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id09CA80W0Z5Z) showing what variables you would need to pass over with your cart upload code.